# Failed to resolve: com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.6.5 Paytm integration

Tags: java, android, gradle, paytm

Problem causing while integrating patym sdk android. Shows that "Failed to resolve: com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.6.5" while doing with latest build:gradle 7.2.1. Please help me to solve this any help will be appretiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify the settings.gradle file with maven repository

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.paytm.in/libs-release-local"
        }
    }
}
```

it will help you do the integration of paytm integration